# Tabs aren't working in Android

Tags: android

I have run into an obstacle where my tabbed layouts are overlapping their content.  I am currently creating an Android app. This is when the first tab is opened. (link to picture below):

[image]

This is what happens when I open the second tab (link to picture below):

[image]

You might notice that the button that says "Button" is overlapping the MainActivity. That is my problem. I don't want them to overlap. I just want the button to show the other activity (no overlapping). Here is part of my MainActivity.java code:

```
package com.example.currencyconverter;


import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    addListenerOnButton();
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setSubtitle("Created By Rohit Nandakumar");
    actionBar.setTitle("Currency Converter"); 
// Specify that tabs should be displayed in the action bar.
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

ActionBar.Tab Frag1 = actionBar.newTab().setText("Converter");
ActionBar.Tab Frag2 = actionBar.newTab().setText("Currencies");
ActionBar.Tab Frag3 = actionBar.newTab().setText("News");

Fragment fragment1 = new Fragment1();
Fragment fragment2 = new Fragment2();
Fragment fragment3 = new Fragment3();

Frag1.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(fragment1));
Frag2.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(fragment2));
Frag3.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(fragment3));

actionBar.addTab(Frag1);
actionBar.addTab(Frag2);
actionBar.addTab(Frag3);
```

Here is Fragment1.java code:

```
package com.example.currencyconverter;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class Fragment1 extends Fragment{
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
}
}
```

Here is my Fragment2.java code:

```
package com.example.currencyconverter;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2, container, false);
}
}
```

Here is my MyTabsListener.java file:

```
package com.example.currencyconverter;

import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.ActionBar.TabListener;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;

public class MyTabsListener implements TabListener {

    public Fragment fragment;

    public MyTabsListener(Fragment fragment) {
        this.fragment = fragment;
    }


    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }



}
```

What is the problem? What am I doing wrong. I have searched Google, but I could not find the solution. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hey I am not too sure but don't you need to do `ft.commit();` after `ft.replace...` everytime? I don't know if that creates the issue but just curious.